# How to use background color opacity in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, opacity

It's work only ff chrome opera safari but not work in ie , woh can i do ?

How to use background color opacity in IE ? Thank you for every answer.

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
background-color:#ffffff;
opacity:0.9;
filter:alpha(opacity=90);
```

Comment: not work ! All element in class will opacity 0.9 too

Answer (score 0):

Old `IE` not support RGBA color mode you can use filter like so:

```
   .transparent_class {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

another option you have is that you can create one transparent img in photoshop,change opacity to 20% ,30%... Then save with png24 than use that for background.

Comment: `opacity` is completely different from `rgba`. The OP doesn't want to apply the `opacity` to all descendants.

Comment: yes! but we do not another option in old IE